# jQuery taking the first PHP result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mobile, jquery-on

I'm trying to select the data that comes from the data base with jQuery, but my problem is that only the first result has a click handler bound to it.

Here is the PHP part:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE rented = '0'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $carName = $row['name'];
            echo '<div id="car" car-name="'.$carName.'">'.$carName.'</div>';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'ολα τα αυτοκινιτακια ειναι νοικιασμενα';
    }

?>
```

and the jQuery part:

```
$('#car').on('click', function(){
        var carName = $(this).attr('car-name');
        alert(carName);
    });
```

Let's say that i'm dynamically creating two *div* elements (because there are only two records in db). The jQuery recognizes only the first one. How can I make it recognize all the *div* elements?

Comment: Try, `$(document).on("click", "#car", function(e) {var carName = $(this).attr('car-name');alert(carName);});`

Comment: ID should not be same for all the divs

Comment: simply use class (class="car") and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access event on class name instead ID

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE rented = '0'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $carName = $row['name'];
            echo '<div class="car" car-name="'.$carName.'">'.$carName.'</div>';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'ολα τα αυτοκινιτακια ειναι νοικιασμενα';
    }

?>
```

JS

```
$('.car').on('click', function(){
        var carName = $(this).attr('data-car-name');
        alert(carName);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of id (#car) use class(.car) for the div

**PHP**

```
echo '<div class="car" car-name="'.$carName.'">'.$carName.'</div>';
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.car').on('click', function(){
        var carName = $(this).attr('car-name');
        alert(carName);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

use in html  `data-car-name="car name"`

and jquery

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $carName = $row['name'];
            echo '<div class="car" data-car-name="'.$carName.'">'.$carName.'</div>';
        }

$('.car').on('click', function(){
        var carName = $(this).attr('data-car-name');
        alert(carName);
    });
```

also yes to @ManiMuthuPandi using classes as well.

Answer (score 1):

$(document).on('click','#car' ,function(){ var carName = $(this).attr('car-name'); alert(carName); });

Because the click handler being attached by browser is faster than your php rendering.If you will attach a click handler on document then it will work always.

Hope this helps

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should add class car:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE rented = '0'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $carName = $row['name'];
        echo '<div class="car" car-name="'.$carName.'">'.$carName.'</div>';
    }
}else{
    echo 'ολα τα αυτοκινιτακια ειναι νοικιασμενα';
}
```

?>

Jquery

```
$('.car').on('click', function(){
    var carName = $(this).attr('car-name');
    alert(carName);
});
```

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

Per the MDN documentation for attribute [**id**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id):

> The id [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)</sup>

So when creating the *div* elements, give them unique values for the *id* attribute. In order to add the click handler to all elements for the car elements, add a *class* attribute (e.g. `class="car"`) to the `<div>` elements:

```
echo '<div id="car_'.$carName.'" car-name="'.$carName.'" class="car">'.$carName.'</div>';
```

Then use the [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) (i.e. `.car`) in the click-handler:

```
$('.car').on('click', function(){
    var carName = $(this).attr('car-name');
    alert(carName);
});
```

See this demonstrated below (with PHP code removed, since this sandbox doesn't support it):

```js
$('.car').on('click', function(){
        var carName = $(this).attr('car-name');
        alert(carName);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="car_MDX" car-name="MDX" class="car">MDX</div>
<div id="car_m3" car-name="m3" class="car">m3</div>
<div id="car_z3" car-name="z3" class="car">z3</div>
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the #car id. Use class:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE rented = '0'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $carName = $row['name'];
            echo '<div class="car" car-name="'.$carName.'">'.$carName.'</div>';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'ολα τα αυτοκινιτακια ειναι νοικιασμενα';
    }

?>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.car').on('click', function(){
        var carName = $(this).attr('car-name');
        alert(carName);
    });
```